# How can I access my docker asp.net core application?

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I have a ASP.NET Core 2.2./PostgreSQL composed docker solution that seems to be working fine amongst the containers.

I have followed a hybrid of the official [Quickstart: Compose and ASP.NET Core with SQL Server](https://docs.docker.com/compose/aspnet-mssql-compose/) and [Quickstart: Compose and Django](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) with a solution for adding node.js into the mix.

<del>In the interest of brevity, I've omitted the actual `Dockerfile` in this post.</del> The `Dockerfile` should be quite standard:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x |  bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]
RUN ["dotnet", "build"]
EXPOSE 80/tcp
EXPOSE 5001/tcp
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh
CMD /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh
```

where `entrypoint.sh` actually fires up the web server and migrates the EF migrations like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
run_cmd="dotnet run"

until dotnet ef database update; do
>&2 echo "PostgreSQL Server is starting up"
sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "PostgreSQL Server is up - executing command"
exec $run_cmd
```

and finally my `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
  aspnetpostgresql:
    driver: bridge

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    networks: 
      - aspnetpostgresql
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
        - "5001:5001"
        - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
        - db
    networks: 
      - aspnetpostgresql
```

The ASP.NET Core image is based on `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2`. Suffice it to say, I have two containers, `my_web_app_db_1` (PostgreSQL) and `my_web_app_web_1` (ASP.NET Core 2.2. React Web App). I have logged into the `my_web_app_web_1`-container and established that the web server is running at https://localhost:5001:

```
root@0123456780:/app# wget -p --no-check-certificate https://localhost:5001
--2019-04-17 19:46:29--  https://localhost:5001/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1, ::1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:5001... connected.
WARNING: The certificate of 'localhost' is not trusted.
WARNING: The certificate of 'localhost' hasn't got a known issuer.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1673 (1.6K) [text/html]
Saving to: 'localhost:5001/index.html'

localhost:5001/index.html                100%[==================================================================================>]   1.63K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

# .... yada yada yada

FINISHED --2019-04-17 19:46:30--
Total wall clock time: 0.4s
Downloaded: 4 files, 3.2M in 0.1s (23.3 MB/s)
```

In other words, everything seems fine on the web server side.

```
ABCDE-MacBook-Pro:MyWebApp MY_USER$ docker-compose ps
      Name                    Command               State                           Ports                         
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
my_web_app_db_1    docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up      5432/tcp                                              
my_web_app_web_1   /bin/sh -c /bin/bash ./ent ...   Up      0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5001->5001/tcp, 80/tcp
```

*Please note:* the `5001` port is also exposed to the host, as can be seen by scrolling right.

However, all attempts at connecting with `https://localhost:5001` are unsuccessful. E.g. running the same `wget` operation from the host gives

```
ABCDE-MacBook-Pro:MyWebApp MY_USER$ wget -p --no-check-certificate https://localhost:5001
--2019-04-17 23:00:05--  https://localhost:5001/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:5001... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Doing a `curl`-operation is equally unsuccessful:

```
ABCDE-MacBook-Pro:MyWebApp MY_USER$ curl -k https://localhost:5001curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:5001
```

Finally, I'm aware that the [`aspnetcore`-image](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore/) is inherently bound to port 80:

> This image sets the ASPNETCORE_URLS environment variable to http://+:80 which means that if you have not explicity set a URL in your application, via app.UseUrl in your Program.cs for example, then your application will be listening on port 80 inside the container.

However, this does not seem to be the case for me, as I'm able to `wget` to port `5001`. Either this does not apply to the SDK image, or the documentation is not up-to-date.

The question is, what do I have to do to access `https://localhost:5001` from the host?

**Update:**

My goal with this set up was to get the database to be created and seeded in accordance with the db entity framework migrations. The resulting 
docker setup was intended to be used by early testers, so large-scale production considerations did not apply.

I'm pretty agnostic when it comes to the exact db initiation mechanisms, but as long as the development is far from finished, my requirement 
has been that the schema is easily maintainable and the migrations are easily deployed. Thus, it would be handy if I can run the

`dotnet ef database update`

command, as this is the exact same thing I'd do in my development environment. After further investigating my initial attempt at dockerizing my project, I decided to take a step back and run the actual migrations from the ASP.NET Core project itself. This is perhaps not the cleanest of solutions, but it solves my actual case: namely having a docker setup replicating my development environment. For those interested, my `Dockerfile` now looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out . 

EXPOSE 80/tcp

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyWebApp.dll"]
```

And the `DbContext` looks like this:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.Migrate();
    }

    // ...

}
```

The `docker-compose.yml` is pretty much the same as before (although I've removed the network config). Now I can access `http://localhost:8000` from the host computer.

Comment: Can you use the same "wget" command from the host and post the error? Also can you try map a bigger port on hosy? (Eg. 50001)

Comment: Thanks for your advice @Mihai, I've updated the question. I'll also look into the port advice.

Comment: So it does establish a connection. Which is good. Maybe wget works different on Mac? I usually use curl with "-k" flag. Maybe you can try this? Or simply run the same in a browser?

Comment: Yeah, I also usually use curl. Added it to the post for reference. Still no good.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post the Dockerfile, I can't say for certain, but do you have an "EXPOSE 5001" in your Dockerfile? Perhaps if this is missing it would cause this behavior.

Comment: Thank's for your suggestion, I realised that the question was better off actually referencing the `Dockerfile`, so it's added now.

Comment: I don't really know .Net but this looks more like a webserver issue. Keep in mind that requests coming from outside the container on the mapped port don't arrive to your webserver as from "localhost". So if your configuration only allows traffic from "localhost" then that's what you need to change. Looking at the dockerfile you use a named stage (build) but then you don't do anything with it. Also maybe the sdk is so configured but the runtime image would allow more traffic?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, @Mihai. I believe you're on the right track. The solution works fine from within the container, the problem seems to be webserver-related. By the way: the "build" stage makes sure the code is compiled before it is used in the `entrypoint.sh`. I guess it could've been carried out as `RUN dotnet build`.

Comment: But then you should have another stage that uses the runtime image and only copies the compiled artefacts and run them.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! As I'm totally new to docker I made the assumption that `RUN ["dotnet", "build"]` was the named stage, however I realise that it is in fact `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build`. I tried to replace the "sdk"-image with the runtime version, but then the build stage failed. I think I need to look into other ways to build my product.